# Error in the Hibernate with not found Persistence

Tags: hibernate, persistence

I'm trying to develop an application with Hibernate and Servelets. Please, can someone help me with this error?

mar 01, 2020 1:19:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke

```
** GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [br.com.app.service.VehicleService] in 
context with path [/App] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an 
exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence **at br.com.app.service.VehicleService.service(VehicleService.java:46)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here are my libraries:

> [image: Libraries]

Here are my struct of files:

> [image: struct files]

My file of persistence:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <!-- Unidade de persistencia -->
  <persistence-unit name="MyPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <!-- Implementação do JPA -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <!-- Lista de entidades -->
    <class>br.com.app.VehicleModel</class>
    <properties>
      <!-- Propriedades JDBC -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/seuBanco"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <!-- Configurações específicas do Hibernate -->
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: please add javax.persistence.jar as dependency.

Comment: Thanks. I added but the same error continues.

Comment: May I suggest using Maven or Gradle for dependency management?